# How to copy file to remote server in Lotusscript

Tags: file, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I want to create a Lotus Notes agent that will run on the server to generate a text file. Once the file is created, I need to send it to a remote server.

What is the best/easiest way to send the file to a remote server?

Thanks

Comment: What protocol are you using? Lotusscript has scant native support for most network protocols, but if you're connecting to a standard fileshare (as opposed to ftp / http etc.) you should be OK

Answer (score 1):

If your "remote" server is on a local windows network, you can simply copy the file from the server file system to a UNC path (\myserver\folder\file.txt) using the FileCopy statement.  If not, you may want to look at using a Java agent, which would make more file transfer protocols easily accessible.

In either case, be sure to understand the security restrictions on Notes agents - for your agent to run on the server and create a file on the server's file system, the agent will need to be flagged with a runtime security level of 2 or 3, and signed by an appropriately authorized ID.

Answer (score 0):

Sending or copying files using O/S like commands to a remote server require that destination  servers be also mapped as drives on your source server. As Ed rightly said, security needs to allow you to save files down onto the server and then try and copy them.

You can generate the file locally on the server and then use FTP commands in a script to send the file. Or if you're a java guru, you can try using Java.FTP to send the file as well. I had some trouble with it, but it should be possible providing an FTP account is setup on the destination server. FTP related stuff by a well known notes guy can be found [here](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm) and [here](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/JavaFtp.htm)

I have done it using a script, and it's clumsy but effective in simply pushing files around. Ideally, if the server at the other end is a Domino server as well, you could actually attach the file in an email and send it to a mailin account on the destination server. I have done that before, and it's great as you can just pass the whole problem of getting files off to the SMTP process.